# check if excel cell value exists in SQL

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have an Excel worksheet that contains part numbers for an order.  I want to query the SQL table of parts to see if each part already exists and, if not, display "New" in a cell.  I already do this by importing the part_number column from sql to excel then  use IFERROR on a VLOOKUP to display the message.

As the sheet grows larger and more workers are remote over VPN, the time it takes to refresh the part_number download is becoming an issue.

Is there a way to use a sql query from Excel, using the past_number cell, to return a value I can test with an IF or something else?  Would need to iterate through each line in the excel worksheet, or could I do it more 'set' oriented?

Comment: Why not include it as an artificial column when you first query the table?

Comment: I think "Iterating through each line and querying the database for a match" is going to be a lot slower than just dragging through parts and doing a vlookup. Your other option would be to have a temp table out on sql server, load your excel table up to it, then query to see which ones are missing from your existing SQL table and send the results back. To @TabAlleman's point where does this "table that contains part numbers for an order" come from? If it comes from the same sql server then you could perform this query before bringing the results down to excel.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I see that I asked this in a confusing way.  I have an EXCEL order table with part_numbers that I need to validate against the part number table in SQL.  Presently, I import the part number column from the SQL table into a hidden tab in EXCEL.  I then use a formula in a cell on the orders table to vlookup to the hidden tab with the SQL import.  I want to see if I do the same thing without importing the part numbers from SQL, and instead query the SQL table to see if the part is already there.

Comment: Excel doesn't have tables, it has worksheets.   That was the source of the confusion.

Comment: I think you are simply storing the data inefficiently. you should be storing the transnational data in a database table. This allows large volumes of data to be queried and checked quickly and efficiently against smaller reference data-sets i.e. the product data and pricing etc.

Comment: @jimmy8ball, how do I query the SQL table from Excel?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dynamic query with parameters in Excel to pull only the part numbers relevant to your order. Here is how you do it:

1. Go to **Data** tab -> **Get Data** -> **From Other Sources** -> **From Microsoft Query**:

[image: Excel, get data from Microsoft Query]

2. Select **New Data Source** or select an existing one if you already had your SQL server data source created before -> click OK:

To create a new data source click **OK**

[image: Excel, Microsoft Query, create new SQL Server datasource]

Enter the server name -> select a driver and click **Connect**

[image: Excel, Microsoft Query, connect]

Enter the server name again and click **"Use Trust Connection"** or enter SQL **Login ID** and **Password** (depending on your enviroment) -> Click **"Options"**

[image: Excel, Microsoft Query, database options]

Select your Database and click **OK** and **OK** again, so you are back to **Choose Data Source** window where you also click **OK**

[image: Excel, Microsoft Query, select existing datasource]

3. On the **Query Window - Choose Columns** window select your PartNumbers table and a column where you store part number's name (or whatever you use to identify it in the order):

[image: Query Wizard - Choose Columns]

Click **Next** 3 times -> **Finish** (leave everything as it is by default) -> Select where to put the results and Click **OK** on the **Import Data** window.

**Note:** I mentioned that Microsoft Query does not handle `nvarchar(MAX)` type well. In my tests if I have a column with nvarchar(MAX) I would see an empty values for that column when I import it into an excel worksheet.

4. Go to **Data** tab -> **Properties** -> **Connection Properties** -> **Definition** tab. Here you can edit **Command Text**:

[image: Microsoft Query: Change Command Text]

Change it to something like:

```
SELECT PartNumbers.[Name] as Name
FROM TestDB.dbo.PartNumbers PartNumbers 
WHERE PartNumbers.[Name] in (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(CAST(? as nvarchar(100)), ','))
```

**Note**, we have a question mark in the SQL query above - it will be your dynamic parameter to filter part numbers.

5. Click **OK** and **Connection Properties** -> **Definition** again
   (required to enable **"Parameters..."** button) -> click **"Parameters..."**

[image: Microsoft Query: Parameters]

On the **Parameters** window select **"Get the value from the following cell"** and select a cell which you will use later to add a dynamic value for the filter (it can be empty for now).

You can also check **"Refresh automatically when cell value changes"** option. Then click OK button on all opened windows, so you are back to excel table which now should have no rows.

6. Now go to that empty cell which you used as a parameter and enter the following formula: `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,[PartNumberValuesRange])`. [PartNumberValuesRange] must be changed to a range which have all the part numbers from your order.
7. Now, if you did everything right you should see how the existing part number records pulled from the database to your table you made during the steps 1-5.

At this point you can use your **VLOOKUP** + **IFERROR** approach to display a corresponding message. The table you reference in the formula will have only a subset of part numbers which exist in both the order in your excel and in the database, so you can easily find all the part numbers which are missing in the database. This should speed up your workflow as you do not need to pull the entire table from the database now.

Comment: Wow, super write-up Peter.  Thanks.  I will give this a try later today or tomorrow.

Comment: Did you have a chance to try it?